# Smartest way to code these tile systems

Tags: jquery, masonry

Currently I am working on a website which consists of multiple of these tile systems you can see below.

[image: Tile layouts]

I am wondering which way would be the best to code them.

I used Masonry which works quite well but it’s a jQuery based solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/xfxYQ/

HTML

```
<div class="box-container">
    <article class="box span-1x1">1</article>
    <article class="box span-1x1">2</article>
    <article class="box span-2x2">3</article>
    <article class="box span-1x1">4</article>
    <article class="box span-1x1">5</article>
    <article class="box span-2x2">6</article>
    <article class="box span-1x1">7</article>
    <article class="box span-1x2">8</article>
    <article class="box span-1x1">9</article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-container {
    width: 240px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: red;
}

.span-1x1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.span-1x2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 110px;
}

.span-2x1 {
    width: 110px;
    height: 50px;
}

.span-2x2 {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Masonry jQuery

```
var $container = $('.box-container');

$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

Does anybody have a smart idea for a plain HTML/CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of CSS grid frameworks with the aim to create things like this.

[960.gs](http://960.gs/)
is also a CSS-based grid framework. There is no Javascript int it, so you could take a look
at its architecture or even use that one.

If you want some animation or something you could animate it with CSS3 if you really don't
want to use any Javascript in it (I also prefer not to).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely have to break that HTML up into columns. Basically this will require rewriting that HTML quite a bit. For example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/dA5K2/):

```
<div class="box-container cf">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box span-1x2">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box span-1x1">1</div>
    <div class="box span-1x1">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box span-2x2">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```